Slepian sequence (DPSS) discrete signal extrapolation
How can Slepian sequences a.k.a digital/discrete prolate spheroidal sequences (DPSS) be used for extrapolation of a discrete signal?
Figure 1. Ten first orthonormal DPSS basis vectors with standardized half bandwidth NW = 10 (see scipy.signal.windows.dpss).

A DPSS basis parameterized by a bandwidth are orthogonal finite-length sequences the shapes of which are unaffected by ideal (sinc) low-pass filtering with the same half bandwidth as the cutoff, and the result truncated to the same length as the input. That's how DPSS can be defined. More mathematically, the low-pass filtering is convolution that can be written as a matrix-vector multiplication with a Toeplitz matrix. When the result is truncated as described, the matrix is square:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  h_{0} & h_{-1} & \cdots & h_{-(N-2)} & h_{-(N-1)} \\
  h_{1} & h_{0} & \cdots & h_{-(N-3)} & h_{-(N-2)} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  h_{N-2} & h_{N-3} & \cdots & h_{0} & h_{-1} \\
  h_{N-1} & h_{N-2} & \cdots & h_{1} & h_{0} \\
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}$$
The elements are symmetrical with $h_k = h_{-k}$ and have the following form with cutoff or half-bandwidth $c$:
$$h_k = \frac{c}{\pi}\,\operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{c}{\pi}k\right) = c\mathrm{\,if\,}k=0,\frac{\sin(c\,k)}{k}\mathrm{\,otherwise}\tag{2}$$
DPSS are the eigenvectors of the matrix. Here is that put into a Python script to calculate the DPSS and to plot a few early ones:
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
c = np.pi/80
A = toeplitz((lambda x: c*np.sinc(c*x))(np.arange(N)))
eigvals, dpss = np.linalg.eig(A)
dpss = dpss.real.T
eigvals = eigvals.real
dpss = dpss*np.expand_dims(np.sign(dpss[:,0]), 1)
for i in range(5):
    plt.plot(dpss[i])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

Figure 1. Five DPSS with the largest eigenvalues for Length $N = 100$ and cutoff $c = \pi/80$.
Looking beyond the start and the end of the sequences and not truncating the convolution, the low-pass filtering creates tails as a form of extrapolation. These extrapolated infinite-length sequences are also orthogonal. A signal can be extrapolated by fitting early finite-length DPSS basis vectors to a signal and by calculating a weighted sum of not the DPSS basis vectors but of their infinite-length extrapolations. These extrapolations can be truncated to give the wanted amount of extrapolation.
The number of basis vectors used and the bandwidth chosen will greatly affect the results. The result may oscillate because using only a few early basis vectors abruptly truncates the DPSS series giving a kind of Gibbs phenomenon, or blow up because of the inherent instability in the extrapolated DPSS basis with a low bandwidth setting (see Figs. 3 & 4). It has been suggested to use a few more basis vectors and to scale by $\lambda^2 / (a + \lambda^2)$ each fitting coefficient associated with a basis vector, where $a$ is some small but sufficiently large number and $\lambda^2$ is the square of the eigenvalue associated with the basis vector. AFAIK the eigenvalue is the gain of the basis vector as it is low-pass filtered.
With this recipe I created the following Python implementation and example.
Figure 2. A target signal (blue) that is a sum of sinusoids, its length $N=100$ portion input to extrapolation (green) extrapolated by DPSS extrapolation (black).
Figure 3. The 10 extrapolated orthonormal DPSS basis vectors used in the example.
Figure 4. Absolute values of the 10 extrapolated orthonormal DPSS basis vectors used in the example (note the logarithmic scale).
To get a reasonable extrapolation with this example, the bandwidth needed to be set much smaller than half the sampling frequency, to a standardized half bandwidth NW$=10$ resulting in a cutoff of $2\pi$ NW $/N = 2\pi/10$, a tenth of the sampling frequency. The regularization constant used was a = 0.000000001.
I don't think the results are that impressive, but perhaps there is an application for this.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal.windows import dpss
from scipy.signal import convolve

# Example signal
f = lambda x: 5*np.sin(x/37+.3)+3*np.sin(x/13+.1)+2*np.sin(x/347+.7)
signal = f(np.arange(100))
target = f(np.arange(1000)) 

# Make extrapolated orthonormal DPSS basis
# q = number of basis vectors
# N = basis vector length
# num_padding = tuple (left, right) of the number of sample points by which to extrapolate the basis vectors
# NW = standardized half bandwidth, see scripy.signal.windows.dpss docs
# Returns:
# * Extrapolated basis vectors in an array of shape (q, left + N + right)
# * Squared eigenvalues associated with the basis vectors as they are low-pass filtered
def extrapolated_orthonormal_dpss_basis(q, N, num_padding, NW):
  # DPSS basis
  dpss_basis = dpss(N, NW, q)
  # Extrapolate
  lp_shift = num_padding[0] + N - 1  # Lowpass filter shift
  lp_len = lp_shift + N + num_padding[1]  # Lowpass filter length
  lp = (lambda x: 2*NW/N*np.sinc(2*NW/N*x))(np.arange(lp_len) - lp_shift)  # Lowpass filter
  ext_dpss_basis = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: convolve(x, lp, mode="valid"), 1, dpss_basis)
  # Calculate squares of eigenvalues and normalize
  sq = np.sum(dpss_basis**2, axis=1)
  sqfiltered = np.sum(ext_dpss_basis[:, num_padding[0]:num_padding[0]+N]**2, axis=1)
  sqeigenvals = sqfiltered/sq
  ext_dpss_basis /= np.sqrt(np.expand_dims(sqfiltered, -1))
  return ext_dpss_basis, sqeigenvals

# Fit an orthonormal basis to a signal
# signal = input signal
# basis = basis vectors
# Returns the coefficients for fitting the vectors
def fit_basis(signal, basis):
  return np.sum(signal*basis, axis=1)

# Extrapolate signal by extrapolating a DPSS basis fitted to signal
# signal = input signal
# q = number of DPSS basis functions
# num_padding = tuple (left, right) of by how many samples to extrapolate
# NW = standardized half bandwidth, see scripy.signal.windows.dpss docs
# a = regularization constant, a sufficiently large small number
def dpss_extrapolate(signal, q, num_padding, NW, a):
  basis, sqeigenvals = extrapolated_orthonormal_dpss_basis(q, signal.shape[0], num_padding, NW)
  coefs = fit_basis(signal, basis[:, num_padding[0]:num_padding[0]+signal.shape[0]])
  coefs = coefs*sqeigenvals/(a + sqeigenvals)  # Regularize
  return np.sum(basis*np.expand_dims(coefs, -1), axis=0)

extrapolated_signal = dpss_extrapolate(signal, 10, (0, (target.shape[0] - signal.shape[0])), 1.0, 0.000000001)
plt.plot(target, 'b')
plt.plot(extrapolated_signal, 'k')
plt.plot(signal, 'g')
plt.show()

References:

Mihálik, O., Michalík, D., Jura, P., & Fiedler, P. (2019). Spectral Super-resolution and Band-limited Extrapolation Using Slepian Series. IFAC-PapersOnLine, 52(27), 388-393.

Telecký, Matyáš & Mihálik, Ondrej. (2024). A Comparison of Popular Band-limited Signal Reconstruction Methods.


